Is $\mathbb{R}$ diffeomorphic to the absolute value graph?
Backstory (skip unless curious): I signed up for a course named "Differential Topology" at my university. I love topology, so I figured it'd be fun and easy for me since I consider myself to be good at topology. Turns out I need to know a lot of calculus, which is my LEAST FAVORITE SUBJECT. I know nothing about calculus and now I can't back out. I'm having a lot of trouble with this course and it's just starting. Please help me understand and get the gist of it! Thanks!
So, I had an assignment for today (I already handed it in incomplete, but I still want to understand how to solve it). Basically, I must prove wether or not $\mathbb{R}$ is diffeomorphic to $A=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2:y=|x|\}$. I believe it isn't, since $A$ has a pointy end. I don't know how to proceed, I really am bad at calculus... I figured out that for these sets to be diffeomorphic, there must exist a biyective function $f:A\to \mathbb{R}$ that is smooth. That is, there must exist an open ball $B=B_r(0,0)$ and a smooth function $f_0:B\to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f|_{A\cap B}=f_0|_{A\cap B}$ (the restrictions concide).
Intuition tells me I should reach the contradiction that if such $f_0$ exists, then it can't be inyective over $A\cap B$, and thus refuting my assumption that such biyective $f$ exists. I have no idea how to reach this conclusion or even if I'm on the right path.
Please help me understand, I don't want to fail this course and it's literally just the second week. If I don't understand now, I'll definitely fail later. Thank you!!!
EDIT: I'm taking the following definition of Diffeomorphisms of subsets of manifolds while viewing $A$ as a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$. Hope that clarifies the question! Thanks to all the people trying to help me, I really appreciate it!

What structure is $A$ endowed with? If it is a differentiable manifold structure, then what is it? If it is not, then what does it mean for $A$ to be "diffeomorphic" to $\mathbb{R}$? (As far as I know, this notion only makes sense for differentiable manifolds. )

Oscar, you may have to brush up on a minimum of calculus, so as to be able to follow, for example, the proof of the existence of an arclength parametrisation of a regular smooth curve.  I can recommend an accessible calculus textbook if you are interested.

@Adayah I just posted an update. Hope that clarifies the question!

@MikhailKatz Thanks so much! Please do recommend me a textbook!

Yes, I would recommend the beautiful book by Jerome Keisler, entitled "Elementary calculus with infinitesimals".  You can dispense with some of the clumsiness of epsilon-delta that plagues calculus students.  See https://people.math.wisc.edu/~hkeisler/calc.html

It's not just calculus — but multivariable analysis — that you will need. You need to understand that the derivative is a linear map and you need to know the inverse function theorem. Does your university not have prerequisites for courses?

Let's do an argument by contradiction; assuming your intuition is correct, there should be some contradiction surrounding the point $\mathcal O = (0,0)$.
Suppose that $X=\mathbb R \subset \mathbb R^2$ is diffeomorphic to $Y=A \subset \mathbb R^2$.  Let $f : \mathbb R \to A$ be a diffeomorphism (my $f$ goes in the other direction than the $f$ in your question). Let $p = f^{-1}(\mathcal O) \in \mathbb R$. To simplify notation we can change coordinates in the domain of $f$, by a translation of the coordinate, so that $p=0$.
We are hunting for a contradiction surrounding $0$ and $\mathcal O=f(0)$. We should expect a contradiction of calculus, not so much a contradiction of set theory as you indicated with your "bijectivity" remark.
So let's walk through the definition that you linked.
Since $f$ is smooth, it follows that the vector valued derivative $df/dt(t_0)$ exists at each $t_0 \in \mathbb R$ and is a continuous function of $t_0$. Now we are going to break the proof into two cases, depending on whether $df/dt(0)$ is the zero vector.
Case 1: $V = df/dt(0)$ is not the zero vector. So $V$ is disjoint from either the first quandrant ray $R_1=\{(t,t) \mid t \ge 0\}$ or the second quadrant ray $R_2=\{(-t,t) \mid t \ge 0\}$. These cases are very similar so I'll assume $V$ is disjoint from $R_1$. Choose $\epsilon > 0$ so that the open ball $B(V,\epsilon) \subset \mathbb R^2$ is disjoint from $R_1$. Using continuity of $df/dt$, choose $\delta>0$ so that $df/dt(\delta)$ and $df/dt(-\delta)$ are both in $B(V,\epsilon)$ and are both nonzero. However, one of the points $f(\delta)$, $f(-\delta)$ is in $R_1$ and the other is in $R_2$. Since all vectors tangent to $R_1$ have positive slope and all vectors tangent to $R_2$ have negative slope, it follows that one of the vectors $df/dt(\delta)$, $df/dt(-\delta)$ is in $R_1$ and the other is in $R_2$. This contradicts that $B(V,\epsilon)$ is disjoint from $R_1$.
Case 2: $V=df/dt(0)$ is the zero vector, $V=(0,0)$. The map $f^{-1} : A \to \mathbb R$ is a diffeomorphism, and so there exists an open $U \subset \mathbb R^2$ containing $\mathcal O$, and a smooth $g : U \to \mathbb R$, such that $g \mid U \cap A = f^{-1} \mid U \cap A$. Consider the function $g \circ f$ which is defined on the open set $W=f^{-1}(U) \subset \mathbb R$ which contains $0$. Note that $h = g \circ f$ is the identity function on $W$, so $dh/dt=1$ at every point of $W$. But this contradicts the multivariable chain rule: $dh/dt(0) = Dg(df/dt(0)) = Dg(V)=Dg(0,0) = 0$.

By the way, you missed a big hint when you signed up for a course on differential topology: back in your first semester calculus course, half of the course was differential calculus. But that's okay, now you'll learn some calculus!

The graph of the absolute value function is not smooth as a submanifold of the plane (due to the "pointy end" that you mentioned); namely, it is not a smooth submanifold.  But as a 1-dimensional manifold, it can be endowed with a natural smooth structure.  For example, integrating arclength along the graph will give an isometry between them (where the graph is endowed with the natural induced metric), which can be viewed as a diffeomorphism.
Note.  According to your later "EDIT", you are indeed interested in the first question, namely whether the graph is a smooth submanifold.  This cannot be the case, because a smooth diffeomorphism of a neighborhood would induce a map between tangent spaces sending the tangent line at every point to the tangent line at its image.  But the graph of $|x|$ does not have a tangent line at the origin (its "slope" would have to be simultaneously $1$ and $-1$ so to speak).

What do you mean by "as a $1$-dimensional manifold, it is smooth"? The graph is a bare set, not a manifold, and there is no natural manifold structure on it that you could assume without defining explicitly.

Since there is a natural induced metric on it, it also induces a natural topology.  Therefore it is naturally a topological 1-dimensional manifold.  Integrating arclength gives an isometry with the line.  We can therefore import the smooth structure of the line. @Adayah

I should have written "there is no natural differentiable manifold structure" (in my private dictionary "manifold" already means "differentiable", which is probably not the case for everyone). I do agree that $A$ is naturally a topological manifold. Nevertheless, I still don't exactly get what you mean. Are you saying that being "smooth" is an intrinsic property of some topological manifolds which $A$ happens to have? Or are you saying that using extra stuff (like metric) we can somehow endow $A$ with a smooth manifold structure (in a debatably "natural" way)?

@Adayah, as an abstract 1-dimensional manifold, this graph does not "notice" that it has a kink at the origin.  Its internal structure is indistinguishable from that of a straight line.

Endowing $A$ with a smooth manifold structure is objectively possible. But every concrete way to do that, including yours, is to a great extent arbitrary. It's the same as every finitely dimensional vector space being indistinguishable from $K^n$, but not in a canonical way. If the way you endow $A$ with a smooth manifold structure is arbitrary (it does not follow from the problem statement), then I don't believe this is a valid answer.

There is a unique smooth structure (up to diffeomorphism) on the topological manifold $\mathbb R$.  @Adayah

Yeah, and...? The problem statement is incomplete because the smooth structure on $A$ is not specified. If there existed a simple canonical way to put such a structure on $A$, it would be semi-reasonable to assume that the problem creator intended $A$ to have it. But if you're trying to say that the implicit intention behind this basic problem is to endow $A$ with the unique-up-to-diffeomorphism smooth structure, with the uniqueness being guaranteed by a relatively advanced theorem - then this seems way too far-fetched.

Whichever smooth structure you place on the OP's set $A$, it will indeed be diffeomorphic to $\mathbb R$.  This specifically answers the OP's question.

It doesn't answer the question, because right now the question is not well posed. One way of fixing the question could be to assign a random smooth structure to $A$. Then indeed, no matter how it's done, your answer will be correct (although, in my opinion, very far from the intended way to treat the problem). But another way to fix the question is to make it ask if there is a smooth embedding $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^2$ with the image equal to $A$. Then your solution is nowhere near correct. I don't see how you can tell that the first fix is more "likely" than the second, or any other.

Both your views are interesting and I'm sure you're both correct, no need to fight over it, hehehe! The fault was mine for not explaining my question correctly! For that, I'm sorry. I just posted an update, I hope you can help me out and really appreciate both of you!

I think what @OscarVernonRodríguez is implicitly assuming here is that $A$ is endowed with a sub manifold structure from the usual smooth manifold structure on $\mathbb R^2$, which would mean it does not have a differentiable structure (right?)

@Chris, right, see his EDIT and my NOTE.
